# Prevent spammers accessing my site by blocking their IP address

Tags: .htaccess, advertising

**Story:**

I have my drupal site hosted in aws. Initially there were so many spam registrations occured. I prevented this completely by google recaptcha. By checking the recent logs in drupal I see the registrations comes from 2 ip address repeatedly.

**Steps I tried to block IP**:

1) Added the code to htaccess:

```
order allow,deny
deny from ***.**.**.*
deny from ***.**.**.*
allow from all
```

When i give these 2 ip address in the htaccess, the site shows Forbidden(tried from other systems too). When I give some other ip i am able to access the site.

2) Drupal ip blocking configuration
When I give these 2 ip address , it says not a valid ip address. Every other ip address it accepts. Then I tried to add sample ip and changed the ip address from the db table 'blocked_ips', then when I load the site, it says it is blocked.

From the drupal log i could see that the hacker is trying to create spam contents. I need to block their IP address. They have prevented me to do so somehow, thats why the above steps do not work.

Something strange is going on. Any ideas to prevent this. All welcome.

Comment: 192.168.44.201 is a local IP address - it would appear your server and local network are compromised. This isn't something Drupal can help you with, get a professional server admin to audit the machines that are involved

Comment: It might be a bit futile to do this. They'll just get a different IP and spam from there, and you need to block that one, then they get another etc ...

Comment: I was gonna suggest something like HTTP:BL but your spammers are unknown to these blacklisting databases :( You can always submit them as spammers though! https://www.drupal.org/project/httpbl

Comment: I know if they want they can change ip. But I am sure this can be solved completely. But for now I wanted to atleast block these ip address. It is not able to do even that. May be if they do not know to change ip :P

Comment: Those addresses are also from private networks @MirzaVU. It would appear your hacker is gaining access from within the same network.

Comment: Hmm some servers report wrong IP addresses in the drupal UI. If you're getting registrations just from these addresses, they might be your cloud server IP addresses no? (Just a guess/suggestion) We were getting our server IP's on our load balanced servers in the "Recent Log Messages" and we had to change some stuff to properly forward the user's IP.

Comment: So how can I check. I have hosted in AWS. I hope they could not get access to it. @Clive

Comment: I don't think they gained any server access... if they did .... they wouldn't go to all that trouble just to spam registrations...

Comment: I too use the load balancer. The ip of instances i use is different from these. Do you want me to check the ip of load balancer

Comment: @MirzaVU You mentioned "hacker" so I assumed you've confirmed that your server/site was compromised - is that not the case?

Comment: I have mentioned because the number of registration has decreased 95% after implementing google recapcha. Also google captcha log says these blocked registration comes from these 2 ip. Also from logs in drupal admin ui, i could see access denied errors from these ip.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/1820048 Have you set `reverse_proxy` to `TRUE` and have your load balancer IP in `$conf['reverse_proxy_addresses']` in your settings.php? If not, you may want to do that first, then you might get totally different (The real) IP's of the attackers. Sounds like your configuration is a little off.

Comment: Apologize for the delay. ssh connection problem. i have change the settings file as suggested. Now i see a different ip of users in the drupal log. Waiting for the spammers. Will update here soon.

Comment: Now, i found the real ip of the spammer. It is 108.61.122.72. When searched this ip in google i could confirm it is spam. I have successfully blocked using htaccess. Thanks to all.

Comment: @MirzaVU I suggest you remove all the real IP's from this question now that it's solved

Comment: Sure, is the email with the format like  'something@drupaladdons.brainhard.net'  spam?